# could not Extract Value from Json with python

Tags: python, json

This is not the duplicate ticket.

I have checked the similar threads, like:

[Parsing JSON with Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855276/parsing-json-with-python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str)

[Python Extract Value from Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996298/python-extract-value-from-json)

But none of them work for me.

The background of my question:

I use the REST API [Groups - Get Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/get-groups) with `filter`:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups?$filter={$filter}&$top={$top}&$skip={$skip}
```

My code:

```
import json, requests, pandas as pd
try:
    from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
except Exception:
    #  !pip install azure.identity
     from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


tenant = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
client = 'yyyyyyyyyyy'
client_secret = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
api = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'


# Generates the access token for the Service Principal
auth = ClientSecretCredential(authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
                                                        tenant_id = tenant,
                                                        client_id = client,
                                                        client_secret = client_secret)
access_token = auth.get_token(api)
access_token = access_token.token

print('\nSuccessfully authenticated.')   

base_url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/'
header = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

base_url_expand = f'{base_url}groups?$filter=name%20eq%20%27TestName%27'

# HTTP GET Request
groups = requests.get(base_url_expand, headers=header)
# Response code (200 = Success; 401 = Unauthorized; 404 = Bad Request)
print(groups)
```

**And the result of the groups is `<Response [200]>`**.

**Then I want to get the `id` based on the name in the Response body:**

So, I use the following the code to get the content of the `groups`:

```
try:
    groups = json.loads(groups.content)

    # Pretty-prints the JSON
    print(json.dumps(groups, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        
except Exception as e:
    print('\nRequest failed:', e)
```

The print result is：

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "bf8f466d-35b0-4620-a11e-xxxxxxx",
            "isOnDedicatedCapacity": false,
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "name": "TestName",
            "type": "Workspace"
        }
    ]
}
```

**However**, I could not extract value `id` from the Json file.

Comment: what is `type(data)` ?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, It is the output the value of the rest api Groups - Get Groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/get-groups, I want to get the group`s Id by the name of the group.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, Update it in the question.

Comment: is the {access_token}your id?

Comment: @DeepBhatt, No, I use PS to create the acces token.

Comment: Please update the answer of "type(groups)"

Comment: @DeepBhatt, Sorry for the unclear info, I have updated the question with more info. I get the groups is `<Response [200]>`, then I use  `groups = json.loads(groups.content)` to get the content of the groups. Would you help me check the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the output of:
    print(type(groups['value'][0]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just straightforward to read the `id` from the response

**Modified in your code**

```
try:
    groups_data = json.loads(groups.content)
    id_value = groups_data.get('value', [])[0].get('id')
    print(id_value)
except Exception as e:
    print('\nRequest failed:', e)
```

It's a good approach to use the `get` method in the dictionary.

**My approach**

```
...... Rest of your code ......
base_url_expand = f'{base_url}groups?$filter=name%20eq%20%27TestName%27'

# HTTP GET Request
response = requests.get(base_url_expand, headers=header)

try:
    data = response.json()
    id_value = data.get('value', [])[0].get('id')
    print(id_value)
except Exception as e:
    print('\nRequest failed:', e)
```

Since the `response` object has the inbuild `json` method to read the json you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

the following should work to get the id:

```
import json

groups = {
    "@odata.context": "http://wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "bf8f466d-35b0-4620-a11e-3xxxxxxx",
            "isReadOnly": False,
            "isOnDedicatedCapacity": False,
            "type": "Workspace",
            "name": "testname",
        }
    ],
}


data = json.loads(json.dumps(groups, indent=4))

for fields in data["value"]:
    print(fields["id"])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I test it and it give the error "Request failed: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable"

Comment: you must be using it somewhere else then! because if you just want to fetch id out of JSON, that works! and that's the title of your query here

Comment: The value of groups is not the directly JSON file, I use groups = json.loads(groups.content) to get it. Now, I do not know how to get the value of the ID in the Response body.

Comment: @joy: I got your query now but I can suggest you the following: save your "groups"  into a JSON file & then read that file. or another way is to convert JSON objects into a dataframe. try to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`field_list` is equal to `data['value']` and `data['value']` is equal to `[{'id': 'bf8f466d-35b0-4620-a11e-3xxxxxxx', 'isReadOnly': False, 'isOnDedicatedCapacity': False, 'type': 'Workspace', 'name': 'testname'}]`

so when you loop `field_list` first element is `{'id': 'bf8f466d-35b0-4620-a11e-3xxxxxxx', 'isReadOnly': False, 'isOnDedicatedCapacity': False, 'type': 'Workspace', 'name': 'testname'}`

so print as `print(fields['id'])`

Solutions :

```
print(data ['value'][0]['id'])
```

or

```
data = groups.json()
field_list = data['value']
for fields in field_list:
    print(fields['id'])
```

or

```
data = groups.json()
field_list = data['value']
for i in range(len(field_list)):
    print(field_list[i]['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried that `print(data ['value'][0]['id'])`, but it not work for me. Because the value of groups is not the directly JSON file, I use `groups = json.loads(groups.content)` to get it. Now, I do not know how to get the value of the ID in the Response body.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a Response object, which, along the actual response content, contains more information such as status code, response headers, URL...
If you are sure the returned data is, and always will be a JSON, you can access it directly:

```py
data = response.json()
```

In your case, getting the id would be as easy as

```py
for item in data['value']:
    id_ = item['id']
```

I have used a loop because 'value' is a list, and id_ variable name because [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is already a built-in name.

Answer (score 1):

After this line `groups = json.loads(groups.content)`, try the below statement

> print(groups['value'][0]['id'])

If the above works, you can loop through the `groups.value` and print all ids as below.

```
for group in groups['value']:
    print(group['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this should work:

```
try:
    groups = groups.json()

    # Pretty-prints the JSON
    print(json.dumps(groups, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    
except Exception as e:
    print('\nRequest failed:', e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by taking a look at what exactly you get when you do

```
groups = requests.get(base_url_expand, headers=header)
[...]
try:
    groups = json.loads(groups.content)
```

`response.content` returns the content of the response, **in bytes**. It refers to **Binary Response content.**
You can check it by

```
print("type groups:",type(groups))
```

Output:

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

If you also do `print(groups)`  you will see a  **b’** at the start of the output. That means the reference is a bytes object.
Now , that is not a `json` object, so you can't access it as a `dict`
To access it as a `dict`, you have to convert it to a `dict` first.
One way is to do it directly

```
groups = response.json())
```

`response.json()` returns a JSON object of the results, or it raises an error if the result was not written in JSON.

This time you have a dict

```
print(type(response.json()))
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Then you can find your way to loop and access the keys, for example

```
groups = response.json()
for i in groups['value']:
    print(i['id'])
```